# Delphi access bind variable through TOraDataSet of ODAC

Tags: oracle, delphi, plsql, odac

I've been trying to access the output of bind variables i.e. `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var_name FROM tbl;` in a TOraDataSet instance of the ODAC library.

The intended variable gets declared twice. Once through FOraDataSet.SQL:

```
DELCARE c_count Integer;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO c_count FROM customers
END;
```

and once through FOraDataSet.Params:

```
var lVariable := FOraDataSet.Params.AddParameter as TOraParam;
lVariable.Name := 'c_count';
lVariable.ParamType := ptOutput;
lVariable.DataType := dtInteger;
lVariable.Value := Null;
```

Despite having two instances of the variable c_count it still won't return the result after a FOraDataSet.Execute. The SQL statement by itself works.

What am I missing or more likely, what have I misunderstood?

### UPDATE:

Despite going down the road of taking the output directly from a regular query involves a lot less hassle, it is important for our project that these values get extracted from the variables.

Comment: Would suggest you just access it as a field from the one row one column query result.

Comment: Of course, you're right @brian. Why overcomplicate things. I should have realised that when I was told to use output variables.

Comment: Going to have to reopen this question. We discovered it's vital for our purposes to access these variables. Suggestions?